# Listening on "Dark Theme" in notification area toggle and be notified of a change

Tags: android, android-theme, android-10.0

I can get `UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK` by calling `resources.configuration.uiMode` and `Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK`.

I need to listen to this variable and change my theme on receiving new value.

I think I could add a `BroadcastReceiver` so I can do a `getSystemService(A_CONSTANT_FROM_Context)` and registering a theme callback similar to `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`. But I only found these in docs: extending `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` on my theme styles and having `values-night`. Question [dark them config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955769/dark-theme-configuration-change-in-android-q) which already has an accepted answer refers to this documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get informed about the `uiMode` change add `configChanges` attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    ...>
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        ...
        android:configChanges="uiMode"/>
</application>
```

And then in you activity listen for the config change:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected Configuration mPrevConfig;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        mPrevConfig = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        configurationChanged(newConfig);
        mPrevConfig = new Configuration(newConfig);
    }

    protected void configurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        if (isNightConfigChanged(newConfig)) { // night mode has changed
            recreate();
            // do your thing
        }
    }

    protected boolean isNightConfigChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        return (newConfig.diff(mPrevConfig) & ActivityInfo.CONFIG_UI_MODE) != 0 && isOnDarkMode(newConfig) != isOnDarkMode(mPrevConfig);
    }
    public static boolean isOnDarkMode(Configuration configuration) {
        return (configuration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;
    }
}
```